# Can Adwords reports be segmented by Country and Gender?

Tags: google-ads-api

The Google Adwords API has different types of reports one can generate. So far I have been able to segment the performance of my Adwords campaigns by Country, Gender and Device (separately).

I would like to go a level deeper, so that I can see the metrics of my campaigns by Country and Device, Country and Gender and so on.

It seems like there's no way of segmenting a report by Country and Gender at the same time. Has anyone been able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gender performance report ( https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/gender-performance-report ) to segment by gender and device.

And geo performance report ( https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/geo-performance-report ) to segment by geo and device.

But you can not segment by gender, country and device.