# Get campaign performance reports broken down by age_range and gender from Adwords using the API

Tags: google-ads-api

Is there a way to get the campaign performance broken down by segments like age, gender and parental status from the Google Adwords API. I am aware that there are separate reports (Gender Performance Report, Age Range Performance Report etc) with the required stats, but I am looking for a consolidated list. The thing is I am able to create a campaign performance report in the UI broken down by the above-said segments and wonder why I cannot find a similiar report in the list of reports in the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/all-reports).

I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588337/can-adwords-reports-be-segmented-by-country-and-gender) answer which says it is not possible but that was in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using reports from Google Analytics. This tool is now very flexible, you can generate your personal reports on the data and lists that interest you. You can simply link your Google Ads account to get clearer data. Moreover, you can integrate other tools, such as [this](https://callgear.com/) for reporting calls as well

I'm using my own reports in Google Analytics now to get combined reports and a lot of data in one field, in one file, it makes data Analytics easier